# Intuitions concerning fundamental groups

Tags: general-topology

I'm recently taking a course in topology and we've just covered the concept of fundamental groups. I know that to visualize $\pi(S^2) = 1$, one can put a rubber band on the surface of the $2$-sphere and imagine the band contracting to a point. However, it occurs to me that the rubber band is "stable" if it lies on one of the great circles; that is, it only deforms to a point "by itself" if we move it a little bit away. Of course this idea is very colloquial in nature. I'm wondering is there a way of translating this intuition to mathematical languages?

Comment: It's not that the curve evolves themselves according to some law. It's you that decide how to move it.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you for your answer. I guess that means on the topological end, we are fine . But clearly something is going on here. In light of your comment, I think I'm essentially asking how to describe curves evolving themselves and what is the "law" here.

Comment: There are different laws that you can impose on it. The one that you are describing looks like the cruve shortening flow: roughly speaking, the curve shortening flow evolve the curve so that the length decreases in the fastest possible way.

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you for offering me a direction to look into. I realized that what I asked seems to be more geometric than topological. I'd be grateful if you could formulate a formal answer to this question, if you have time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you contrast the sphere with a circle, then you can see that the hole in the middle prevents you from deforming a loop that goes all the way around to a point.  In a sense, the fundamental group measures the number of one-dimensional holes.  The sphere doesn't have any, so its fundamental group is trivial.

A torus, $S^1\times S^1$, sort of has two holes.  So we get $\Bbb Z^2$.